# How to List contacts of those having the same app installed

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm building a Hybrid mobile app using phonegap with cordova. This is like a social app like whatsapp. I need to list the contacts inside my phone having the same app installed. How can I find-out the contacts of those who installed the app. I know we can read the contacts and post it to server for identifying the users. Is this the way to do that, or anything better are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern to achieve this is to identify every user of your app with a personal data like the email or the phone number.

Then, before showing the contact list, your app should send the phone/user contact list to your server: here you will search, inside your database, for other registered users using the same identification data (phone or email).

The server will respond to the app with a list of user contacts that are using the same (your) app: your app will show them.

Keep in mind that **you must be compliant with security and privacy rules** of your country and that not every country allow you to retain all these data.